# Designing a beautiful Android app

Tags: android, cordova, layout, adt

I'm a new `Android` developer and I need to create an Android application which looks like Apple's App store (on both phone and tablet).

I'm a bit familiar with `Native` layout designer in Eclipse (ADT) and I find it really hard to design such an amazing UI.

I've searched a lot and I've found some web-based UI frameworks such as `Phonegap` and `Chocolatechip-UI`. Are these frameworks capable of designing such apps or not? Or do you suggest something else?

Thnx in advance

Comment: Your app looks beautiful when you give your best.

Comment: Dear @Haresh. We won't create a wheel twice :) If there is a powerful designing framework to do so, why do I have to spend a lot of time and money to do my best?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does not have a right or wrong answer. It really depends on how complex your UI is. How sleek you want it to be.

If your UI is pretty but simple and does not require very complex animations you could go for PhoneGap. however, if you have got very complex UI and want very sleek animations I suggest you use the native APIs.

This however, may change in the near future as web technology is improving really fast :)

Comment: Tnx for your answer. I don't know exactly what u consider as "complex". Is a simple slideshow and also some "loading on demand" (load on page scroll) considered as complex? (They are all being read from an SQL Server remote database)

Comment: If it was me I would have gone for the Web solution. It does not seem anything complex to me. But that is my opinion based on what you told me

Comment: I'm so thankful for your answers :) but just one more question. Which framework do you suggest me? If you have experiences in using different web frameworks.

Comment: To be honest I have never worked with Web Frameworks on Android but I know PhoneGap is the one that I hear a lot when they talk about HTML5 apps.

Comment: You helped me a lot dear hoomi :) tnx

Comment: @PayamSh np Glad I could help!!